# How to configure SNI so as to have benifits of SNI

Tags: apache-2.2, sni

How can i configure SNI to get the benifts ...........I am using openssl 1.0.0 beta5 and apache 2.2.14.
Can anyone tell me the complete procedure . I am configuring virtual host in ssl.conf files and having diff certs to each site hosted on apache.

Need help its urgent

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that SNI is not supported on Internet Explorer on Windows XP. Depending on the user base for your site/s this may be a big concern for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2) seems to say that you only need to have an OpenSSL which supports SNI, which should do as you need Apache 2.2.12 and OpenSSL 0.9.8j or better, the rest of the configuration should be the same as normal [SSL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) configuration in apache, that is, adding something like :

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/your.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/your.key"
SSLVerifyClient None
```

to your vhost.

You may add a :

```
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
```

if you see fit.

Comment: Plus you need the NameVirtualHost directive.
See here:
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

Comment: @Surranó but you've always needed NameVirtualHost with apache 2.2, wether you need ssl, sni or not. And you don't need it starting with apache 2.4.